# Set no text on JTextFormattedField with NumberFormat

Tags: java, swing, number-formatting, jformattedtextfield

I have a number format like this:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
```

And a formatted text field:

```
JFormattedTextField score = new JFormattedTextField(format)
```

In my code I have then:

```
score.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {                

@Override
public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    }

@Override
public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    if (someValue >= 0)
        score.setText(Integer.toString(someValue));
    else
        score.setText("");
    }
});
```

I was trying to convert the input for the score text field only if the value >= 0, if not just leave it empty. This code is not working properly, in fact, if I try to save a positive value, say 4, then I try to  change it to a negative value it doesn't work properly.

Is there a way to make this happen? I would like to display all values >= 0 but "hide" the negative values, so that, say -5, is like converted to a null value.

EDIT:
As suggested by Prasad Karunagoda i tried to use NumberFormmater but i can't handle one situation:

I have in the FocusGained method the if statement to check if `someValue` il >=0, and if so, set the text. I have the value preset, set to -1, before the user can edit it, so the first time it works well. Now say the user modifies the text and sets a valid number (the formatter has a Minimum property set to 0 again as suggested by Prasad Karunagoda), say 5,and it's all good.

Now i have a button that resets this `someValue` to -1, so when the user enters the text to modify, the value of the text is 5 (the last valid number the user entered). What i wanted though is to set the text empty after the press of the button to reset `someValue` to -1 and not to display the old value, is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean with _doesn't work properly._ What do you expect and what does actually happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `JFormattedTextField` reject negative numbers by using `NumberFormatter` and setting its minimum to 0. Try below example.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class FieldRangeTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter();
    formatter.setMinimum(0);
    JFormattedTextField formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Formatted text field"));
    frame.getContentPane().add(formattedTextField);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Text field"));
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JTextField(20));
    frame.setBounds(300, 200, 400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```